# A readonly and read/write connection to the same postgres db in Django

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm wanting to use the same Postgres DB with 2 different postgres roles.  One of which can write to any table and one that can only write to the django_session table.

When I create this in the DATABASES settings, pytest (with xdist) wants to create databases for each set of DATABASE settings and goes boom because the DB already exists and can't be created.  I'd like to create ONLY the readwrite DB and NOT the readonly DB, I essentially want it to be considered an externally controlled DB.  But there seems to be no setting in DATABASES to indicate that.  Only at the model level which of course won't work because I need those tables to be created on the R/W DB Connection

Disallowing migrations in the router doesn't help here either, I'm thinking that that part must not be checked until after the connection to the DB is setup and usable and that is failing because the DB already exists.